# how to use sqlite3 on older php version or how can I use sqlite on older phpversion

Tags: php, web-services

I just want to ask on how to use sqlite3 on older php version or how can I use sqlite on older phpversion i'm currently using 000webhost as my webhost.  Thanks in advance,

Comment: please define "older php version". 5.2.17 as 000webhost greets in headers?

Comment: hi sorry that's also my problem the webhost i'm using is not allowing me to view the php version they're using.

Comment: i found this tutorial and it's kinda working but having this error opening the db 

Warning: sqlite_open() [function.sqlite-open]: file is encrypted or is not a database in /home/a5699305/public_html/viewcategory.php on line 19

line 19 is  $dbhandle = sqlite_open('apollo.db', 0666, $error);

Comment: tutorial is http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitephp/